# VB.NET watermark on a picture

Tags: vb.net, image, watermark

I asked earlier about a way to add a watermark to a picture using visual basic . and thanks to everybody i managed to find a way , but now it seems like I need a code for an option to make the user select the coordinates of the new watermark position on the picture.

Here is my code

```
Dim Image1 As New Bitmap(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
Dim Image2 As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)
Dim Result As New Bitmap(Math.Max(Image1.Width, Image2.Width), _
    Image1.Height + Image2.Height)
Dim gResult As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Result)
gResult.DrawImage(Image1, New Point(0, 0))
gResult.DrawImage(Image2, New Point(0, Image1.Height))
gResult.Dispose()
gResult = Nothing


PictureBox5.Image = Result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a way to do it . you can use 2 pictureboxes and add a code to move the watermark picturebox . you can save everything at the end using a screenshot method .